# Search in DataGridView, How to filter in filtered row

Tags: c#, search, filter, datagridview

When I search for the first column, the rows are filtered. When I filter on the 2nd row among the filtered columns, the filtering on the first column disappears. Again, the word I am looking for in the whole table is searching in the 2nd column.

I want to try this;
I have 4 columns. When I search in the 1st column, the datagridview is filtered by 1. Let it be filtered again when I search in the 2nd column among the filtered ones. When I search in the 3rd column among the filtered ones, I want to see the result I want to see in the 4th column.

I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18

here is my code:

```
     SqlConnection baglan = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-27K77RI\\WINCC;Initial Catalog=lazer;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataTable table;

        private void CWARA_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            searchData1Malzeme(" ");
            searchData2Malzeme(" ");
            searchData3Malzeme(" ");
            searchDataKaynakTürü(" ");

        }
        private void searchDataBeğeni(string valueToSearch)
        {
            string query = "Select Beğeni,[1.Malz],[2.Malz],[3.Malz],KaynakTürü FROM CW where Beğeni like '%" + valueToSearch + "%'";
            command = new SqlCommand(query, baglan);
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            cwGrid.DataSource = table;

        }
        private void searchData1Malzeme(string valueToSearch)
        {
            string query = "Select Beğeni,[1.Malz],[2.Malz],[3.Malz],KaynakTürü FROM CW where [1.Malz] like '%" + valueToSearch + "%'";
            command = new SqlCommand(query, baglan);
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            cwGrid.DataSource = table;

        }
        private void searchData2Malzeme(string valueToSearch)
        {
            string query = "Select Beğeni,[1.Malz],[2.Malz],[3.Malz],KaynakTürü FROM CW where [2.Malz] like '%" + valueToSearch + "%'";
            command = new SqlCommand(query, baglan);
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            cwGrid.DataSource = table;

        }
        private void searchData3Malzeme(string valueToSearch)
        {
            string query = "Select Beğeni,[1.Malz],[2.Malz],[3.Malz],KaynakTürü FROM CW where [3.Malz] like '%" + valueToSearch + "%'";
            command = new SqlCommand(query, baglan);
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            cwGrid.DataSource = table;

        }
        private void searchDataKaynakTürü(string valueToSearch)
        {
            string query = "Select Beğeni,[1.Malz],[2.Malz],[3.Malz],KaynakTürü FROM CW where 
 KaynakTürü like '%" + valueToSearch + "%'";
            command = new SqlCommand(query, baglan);
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            cwGrid.DataSource = table;

        }
        private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string valueToSearch = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
            searchData1Malzeme(valueToSearch);
           
        }
        private void comboBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string valueToSearch = comboBox2.Text.ToString();
            searchData2Malzeme(valueToSearch);

        }
        private void comboBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string valueToSearch = comboBox3.Text.ToString();
            searchData3Malzeme(valueToSearch);
        }
        private void comboBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string valueToSearch = comboBox4.Text.ToString();
            searchDataKaynakTürü(valueToSearch);
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are asking. I am guessing that is what you want is a compound query using the AND condition. Example, in each of the posted queries there is a “single” LIKE condition… `… where [3.Malz] like '%" + valueToSearch + "%'"` … I assume is what you want to do is “AND” the conditions you want, something like… `… FROM CW where [1.Malz] like '%" + valueToSearch1 + "%' AND [2.Malz] like valueToSerach2 AND [3.Malz] Like valueToSearch3…"`  etc.…

Comment: Again, this is just a guess. In addition, it is highly recommended you use SQL parameters for the “values To Search” as opposed to using the values directly to avoid possible SQL injection. In most environments, NOT using SQL parameters is a valid reason to reject your code.

Comment: Hey JohnG. 

Thanks for your feedback. My question is; I want to search first [1.Malz], after filtering I want to search [2.Malz] in filtered [1.Malz], and also again I want to search [3.Malz] in filtered [2.Malz]. Thank you for your comment I tried and it is working succesfully. (adding ADD between them).

but I have another problem in here. I have [1.Malz], [2.Malz], [3.Malz], [KaynakTürü], [ÜrünNo]. As I explained, I wanted to filterin in filtered. But sometimes I wont use [3.Malz], so it meains it can be empty. when I try your advice, it doenst show [KaynakTürü] because [3.Malz] empty.

Comment: string query = "Select *FROM CW where [1.Malz] like '%" + comboBox1.Text + "%' AND [2.Malz] like '%" + comboBox2.Text + "%' AND [3.Malz] like '%" + comboBox3.Text + "%' AND KaynakTürü like '%" + comboBox4.Text + "%'";

Comment: I used this code (upper)
In my database, 
[1.Malz] and [2.Malz] is not empty, but sometimes [3.Malz] can be empty, [KaynakTürü], [ÜrünNo] is depend on [1.Malz] and [2.Malz] or if [3.Malz] is not empty

Comment: If the combo box text is empty, then don’t search on that value. I suggest you create a method that returns the query string. In that method you could check to see if combo box X is empty, if its not empty then “add” that to the query string, if the combo box X IS EMPTY then do not add that to the query string. You should do this anyway since you can see from the posted code, that all four `searchDataX…` methods are identical except for the query string. Create one method to “create” the query string, then call a single method that runs the created passed in query string.

Comment: thanks againg JohnG. I got your advice. I will try it and I will share the result with you. When I success, I will also share the code that I completed. (By the way, I writed to you by addind ADD (on above) İts keyboard fail. I add “AND” as you are in my code.